shacn ui cmdk command component not working on react 19 RC and Next.js 15
I have my cop/past components from shacn/ui the command component as:
    'use client';

import * as React from 'react';
import { type DialogProps } from '@radix-ui/react-dialog';
import { Command as CommandPrimitive } from 'cmdk';
import { Search } from 'lucide-react';

import { cn } from '@/app/lib/utils';
import { Dialog, DialogContent } from '@/components/ui/dialog';

const Command = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof CommandPrimitive>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof CommandPrimitive>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <CommandPrimitive
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      'flex h-full w-full flex-col overflow-hidden rounded-md bg-popover text-popover-foreground',
      className,
    )}
    {...props}
  />
));
Command.displayName = CommandPrimitive.displayName;

interface CommandDialogProps extends DialogProps {}

const CommandDialog = ({ children, ...props }: CommandDialogProps) => {
  return (
    <Dialog {...props}>
      <DialogContent className="overflow-hidden p-0 shadow-lg">
        <Command className="[&_[cmdk-group-heading]]:px-2 [&_[cmdk-group-heading]]:font-medium [&_[cmdk-group-heading]]:text-muted-foreground [&_[cmdk-group]:not([hidden])_~[cmdk-group]]:pt-0 [&_[cmdk-group]]:px-2 [&_[cmdk-input-wrapper]_svg]:h-5 [&_[cmdk-input-wrapper]_svg]:w-5 [&_[cmdk-input]]:h-12 [&_[cmdk-item]]:px-2 [&_[cmdk-item]]:py-3 [&_[cmdk-item]_svg]:h-5 [&_[cmdk-item]_svg]:w-5">
          {children}
        </Command>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

const CommandInput = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof CommandPrimitive.Input>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof CommandPrimitive.Input>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <div className="flex items-center border-b px-3" cmdk-input-wrapper="">
    <Search className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50" />
    <CommandPrimitive.Input
      ref={ref}
      className={cn(
        'flex h-11 w-full rounded-md bg-transparent py-3 text-sm outline-none placeholder:text-muted-foreground disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50',
        className,
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  </div>
));

CommandInput.displayName = CommandPrimitive.Input.displayName;

const CommandList = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof CommandPrimitive.List>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof CommandPrimitive.List>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <CommandPrimitive.List
    ref={ref}
    className={cn('max-h-[300px] overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden', className)}
    {...props}
  />
));

CommandList.displayName = CommandPrimitive.List.displayName;

const CommandEmpty = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof CommandPrimitive.Empty>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof CommandPrimitive.Empty>
>((props, ref) => (
  <CommandPrimitive.Empty
    ref={ref}
    className="py-6 text-center text-sm"
    {...props}
  />
));

CommandEmpty.displayName = CommandPrimitive.Empty.displayName;

const CommandGroup = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof CommandPrimitive.Group>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof CommandPrimitive.Group>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <CommandPrimitive.Group
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      'overflow-hidden p-1 text-foreground [&_[cmdk-group-heading]]:px-2 [&_[cmdk-group-heading]]:py-1.5 [&_[cmdk-group-heading]]:text-xs [&_[cmdk-group-heading]]:font-medium [&_[cmdk-group-heading]]:text-muted-foreground',
      className,
    )}
    {...props}
  />
));

CommandGroup.displayName = CommandPrimitive.Group.displayName;

const CommandSeparator = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof CommandPrimitive.Separator>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof CommandPrimitive.Separator>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <CommandPrimitive.Separator
    ref={ref}
    className={cn('-mx-1 h-px bg-border', className)}
    {...props}
  />
));
CommandSeparator.displayName = CommandPrimitive.Separator.displayName;

const CommandItem = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof CommandPrimitive.Item>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof CommandPrimitive.Item>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <CommandPrimitive.Item
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      "relative flex cursor-default select-none items-center gap-2 rounded-sm px-2 py-1.5 text-sm outline-none data-[disabled=true]:pointer-events-none data-[selected='true']:bg-accent data-[selected=true]:text-accent-foreground data-[disabled=true]:opacity-50 [&_svg]:pointer-events-none [&_svg]:size-4 [&_svg]:shrink-0",
      className,
    )}
    {...props}
  />
));

CommandItem.displayName = CommandPrimitive.Item.displayName;

const CommandShortcut = ({
  className,
  ...props
}: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>) => {
  return (
    <span
      className={cn(
        'ml-auto text-xs tracking-widest text-muted-foreground',
        className,
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
CommandShortcut.displayName = 'CommandShortcut';

export {
  Command,
  CommandDialog,
  CommandInput,
  CommandList,
  CommandEmpty,
  CommandGroup,
  CommandItem,
  CommandShortcut,
  CommandSeparator,
};

I am using Nextjs 15 and this is my package.json:
    {
  "name": "portal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -H 0.0.0.0 --turbopack",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -H 0.0.0.0",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.1.5",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.9.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-scroll-area": "^1.2.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^1.2.2",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.20.5",
    "@tanstack/react-virtual": "^3.10.8",
    "@tremor/react": "^3.18.3",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "cmdk": "^1.0.1",
    "date-fns": "^4.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.36.0",
    "drizzle-zod": "^0.5.1",
    "ldapts": "^7.2.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.454.0",
    "next": "15.0.2",
    "next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.25",
    "outline": "link:@heroicons/react/24/outline",
    "postgres": "^3.4.5",
    "react": "19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028",
    "react-day-picker": "8.10.1",
    "react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.53.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.4",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "use-debounce": "^10.0.4",
    "zod": "^3.23.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.27.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "15.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

But I get the following error:
Unhandled Runtime Error
 Error: Copy to clipboard is not supported in this browser
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReactDebugCurrentFrame')

Source
components/ui/command.tsx (5:1) @ [project]/components/ui/command.tsx [app-client] (ecmascript)

  3 | import * as React from 'react';
  4 | import { type DialogProps } from '@radix-ui/react-dialog';
> 5 | import { Command as CommandPrimitive } from 'cmdk';
    | ^
  6 | import { Search } from 'lucide-react';
  7 |
  8 | import { cn } from '@/app/lib/utils';
Call Stack
Next.js
<unknown>
[turbopack]/browser/runtime/base/dev-base.ts (205:21)
runModuleExecutionHooks
[turbopack]/browser/runtime/base/dev-base.ts (264:5)
instantiateModule
[turbopack]/browser/runtime/base/dev-base.ts (203:5)
getOrInstantiateModuleFromParent
[turbopack]/browser/runtime/base/dev-base.ts (132:10)
esmImport
[turbopack]/shared/runtime-utils.ts (214:18)
[project]/components/ui/combobox.tsx [app-client] (ecmascript)
components/ui/combobox.tsx (4:1)
Next.js
<unknown>
[turbopack]/browser/runtime/base/dev-base.ts (205:21)
runModuleExecutionHooks
[turbopack]/browser/runtime/base/dev-base.ts (264:5)
instantiateModule
[turbopack]/browser/runtime/base/dev-base.ts (203:5)
getOrInstantiateModuleFromParent
[turbopack]/browser/runtime/base/dev-base.ts (132:10)
commonJsRequire
[turbopack]/shared/runtime-utils.ts (241:18)
React
requireModule
node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028__react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-turbopack/cjs/react-server-dom-turbopack-client.browser.development.js (108:27)
initializeModuleChunk
node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028__react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-turbopack/cjs/react-server-dom-turbopack-client.browser.development.js (1051:21)
readChunk
node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028__react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-turbopack/cjs/react-server-dom-turbopack-client.browser.development.js (925:11)
react-stack-bottom-frame
node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028__react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-client.development.js (22444:18)
beginWork
node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028__react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-client.development.js (9583:24)
runWithFiberInDEV
node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028__react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-client.development.js (543:16)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028__react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-client.development.js (14987:22)
workLoopConcurrent
node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028__react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-client.development.js (14981:9)
renderRootConcurrent
node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028__react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-client.development.js (14956:15)
performWorkOnRoot
node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028__react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-client.development.js (14288:11)
performWorkOnRootViaSchedulerTask
node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028__react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-client.development.js (15844:7)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules/.pnpm/next@15.0.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028_react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028__react@19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (44:48)


Using this version resolved the error ""cmdk": "1.0.0""
I also see that you are missing the "overrides"
my configuration: ""overrides": { "@types/react": "npm:types-react@19.0.0-rc.1", "@types/react-dom": "npm:types-react-dom@19.0.0-rc.1", "react-is": "19.0.0-rc-65a56d0e-20241020" }"
https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/react-19
